# writing to a file problem

Tags: java, file-io

I am using this code to write to a file in java. it has always worked and I am 100% sure its right. But still the file does not get written.
I don't even get an error.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;   
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class writetofile {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        FileWriter fw;

        try {
            fw = new FileWriter("testfile.txt");

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write("this is test");

            bw.write("this is test");
            bw.write("this is test");


        } catch (IOException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Could it be some other problem?

Comment: Never be 100% sure, but 100% inquisitive ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `fw.flush()` and `fw.close()`

Comment: +1: ...but `bw.close()` automatically calls `bw.flush()`, so you could get away with just calling close.

Comment: thanks so much! i cant believe i dint do that :P

Comment: :) that always happens in a hurry

Comment: those should be bw.flush() and bw.close(), calling the fw functions wont flush the bufferedWriter

Answer (score 8):

You are not calling the `close()` method on the `BufferedWriter` object. That means the buffers never get flushed.  Add `bw.close()` after your last `bw.write()` statements.

Comment: thanks so much! i dont know i how missed that! super stupid! sorry!

Comment: @jillika: I'm sure it has happend to every single Java programmer out there, and more than once.

Answer (score 3):

You need to flush the buffer and you should close the file as well:

```
try {
            fw = new FileWriter("/tmp/testfile.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("this is test");
            bw.write("this is test");
            bw.write("this is test");
            bw.flush();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Also you should handle the IOException from the actual file writing separately from the file closing so you won't leave the file descriptor opened at the end:

```
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter("/tmp/testfile.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("this is test");
        bw.write("this is test");
        bw.write("this is test");
        bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fw != null) {
                fw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1, the only as far who mentions closing in `finally`, the right way. Note that `flush()` is still unnecessary as `close()` implicitly does that. But that doesn't hurt. Not closing in `finally` may hurt more in exceptional cases.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you call `bw.close()` *before* your method exits. If the buffer doesn't get flushed your file wont get written.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the stream with `sw.close()` or the data may still be cached and not actually written to disk.